# I have aproblem with windows service

Tags: c#

i have a problem with my windows service program
i try to create a windows service to read data from a database and insert them into an other database but when i read data from first db and copy it into a dataset i have a problem, i can't read those data from data set and insert it into an other dataset to insert it into the other database
here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace WindowSeriveDemo
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=DEVELOPER-PC\DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=NMSys;User ID=sa;Password=2649940931";
        string connection2 = @"Data Source=DEVELOPER-PC\DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=Dpardazesh;User ID=sa;Password=2649940931";


        private Timer ServiceTimer = new Timer();

        private int inProcess = 0;
        public const string SP_dataRead = "usp_Read_Data_From_DpardazeshDB";
        public const string SP_insertData = "usp_Write_Data_Into_NMSysDB";
        private IEnumerable<DataRow> item;
        //Timer timer1 = new Timer();

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            setupTimer();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {


            //ServiceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);

        }
        private void setupTimer()
        {
            ServiceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ServiceTimer_Tick);
            ServiceTimer.Interval = 10000;
            ServiceTimer.Enabled = true;
            ServiceTimer.Start();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            //timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void SyncDatabases()
        {
            inProcess = 1;



            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connection2);

            try
            {
                conn2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_dataRead);
                winservDS dataSet = new winservDS();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //AddParameter(cmd);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SP_dataRead, conn2);
                adapter.Fill(dataSet, dataSet.usp_Read_Data_From_DpardazeshDB.TableName);
                dataSet.AcceptChanges();

                return ;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string text = ex.Message;
            }


            inProcess = 0;
        }

         private static SqlCommand cmdGetIdentity;
         public winservDS InsertUsers(IDictionary ids)
         {
             inProcess = 1;


             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
             SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connection2);
             conn.Open();
             conn2.Open();
             winservDS updates = new winservDS();
             DataRow dr;
             dr = updates.usp_Read_Data_From_DpardazeshDB.NewRow();

             foreach (DictionaryEntry i in ids)
             {
                 if (i.Value == null)
                     dr[i.Key.ToString()] = DBNull.Value;
                 else
                     dr[i.Key.ToString()] = i.Value;
             }
             updates.usp_Read_Data_From_DpardazeshDB.Rows.Add(dr);
             try
             {
                 winservDS.usp_Read_Data_From_DpardazeshDBDataTable tbl = updates.usp_Read_Data_From_DpardazeshDB;
                 //Create the adapter initial
                 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                 dataAdapter.InsertCommand = WriteDatabase(conn);

                 //Roll Back the changes if some one error have
                 dataAdapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = false;

                 cmdGetIdentity = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", conn);
                 dataAdapter.RowUpdated += new SqlRowUpdatedEventHandler(HandleRowUpdated);

                 dataAdapter.Update(tbl.Select("", "", DataViewRowState.Added));
                 return updates;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
             }
             inProcess = 0;
         }

       private static void HandleRowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue) && (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert))
                {
                    e.Row["id"] = Convert.ToInt32 (cmdGetIdentity.ExecuteScalar());
                    e.Row.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }


       private static SqlCommand WriteDatabase(SqlConnection conn)
        {


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_insertData);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameterCollection pc = cmd.Parameters;

                pc.Add(CreateParameter("@fHitType", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
                pc.Add(CreateParameter("@DateOfHit", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));
                pc.Add(CreateParameter("@TimeOfHit", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
                pc.Add(CreateParameter("@fEmpid", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return cmd;

        }

        private static SqlParameter CreateParameter(string p, SqlDbType sqlDbType)
        {
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@" + p, sqlDbType);
            parameter.SourceColumn = p;
            return parameter;
        }

        private void ServiceTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inProcess == 0)
            {
                ServiceTimer.Stop();
                SyncDatabases();
                CopyData();
                //InsertUsers(ids);
                ServiceTimer.Start();
            }

        }


        private void CopyData()
        {
            DataSet ds1 = new winservDS();
            DataSet ds2 = new In_Out_RecordsDS();

            foreach (DataRow item in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(item);


            }


        } here
```

Comment: What error do you get? Saying "I have a problem" isn't very helpful if you don't tell us what the problem is. Do you get an error message? Does the program crash? Does it insert the wrong data, or no data at all? That's a lot of code for us to read through, especially if we don't know what's happening. Run your program in debug mode, and post the snippet of code where the error actually happens (plus any bits we absolutely need in order to understand that snippet).

Comment: ok let's Explain my problem for you
i want read data from db1 and insert it into db2
for this i try to create a windows service
in my windows service at first i read data from db1 and copy them to one dataset
at next a want to create new dataset and copy data from first dataset into it
at the end i want to read data from second dataset and insert them into db2

Comment: You just described what you want to happen, but have not told anything about what is preventing it from happening. We know what you want, but was exactly is the problem?

Comment: So, that's what you're trying to do, I understand that part. My question is: what happens? You say you're having a problem with that, so I assume somehow it goes wrong. How? What happens when you run your code?

Comment: now when i read data from db 1 i dont have any problem but when i try to copy them into other dataset i have this problem" my datarow is empty and don't copy data into other dataset

Comment: did you have team viewer to show you my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a DataReader for the source recordsets, read all columns into variables and then insert them into second database with an INSERT Statement. Be avoid of your transaction log when copying thousands of records...

Comment: what should i do exactly ?
please show me with code if it's possible for you